# Network Solutions MySQL setup vs. Go Daddy MySQL setup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, networking

This is difficult to explain so bear with me.

I do not understand how to setup a MySQL database in Network Solutions and know for sure it is somehow linked to a specific domain and on the same server.

Client requires a blog to be embedded so I found this link http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages as a way of embedding a blog.

This is an example of a piece of code to pull the WP posts...

```
<?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/var/www/example.com/wordpress/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');
?>
```

As you see above, I need to be certain the WP data, blog, whatever is on the same root folder / server as the page I'm working on.  Say the page is example.com/newblog.php  I want to paste this code and know the MySQL database is on the same server.

On Go Daddy, this is quite easy and clear to see.  It's clear because I can click the name "example.com" and know i'm about to setup a MySQL database which resides on the same server.

Or am I not understanding how databases are created and where they are stored?  When you create a MySQL database on any server, is it just on it's own and separate from the domain?

Network Solutions is hard to navigate.  I would love to click a domain name being worked on, setup MySQL, and know they're on the same server.

I currently see 2 domain names listed but I'm afraid if I create a new MySQL database, it will be "linked" or associated with the wrong domain.  Or am I safe to just create one and it won't effect the wrong domain?

Comment: You probably would contact support better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL servers provided by both GoDaddy and Network Solutions are typically on different servers than the hosted websites themselves.  At the very least, they are on separate virtual servers from the hosting server.

Just look at the `wp-config.php` file and see what the value of `DB_HOST` is.  This tells you what server the MySQL data is on.  It doesn't really matter if the data is on the same server or not, as long as you are connecting to the correct MySQL host with the correct credentials for that host and your client hostname/IP is allowed to connect using the supplied credentials.

If you have the code:

```
<?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/var/www/example.com/wordpress/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');
```

The only thing that really matters is that the script making that call is on the same server as the Wordpress blog.  Where the MySQL data is doesn't matter.  It's using the same credentials that the wordpress site in question is using so its going to be accessing the same data.

Does that help?

Comment: "or virtual hosts" - what does this mean in the context of mysql server?

Comment: Yes but I'm disappointed that it was THAT easy!  Thank you!!!  I thought it was somehow all tied together and the MySQL database had to be on the same host / domain registrar as the wordpress program.  Thank you again!

Comment: @zerkms No idea, so I have removed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.